# eas build error after expo upgrade from Expo-48 to 49 at "Invalid Podfile file: Couldn't parse JSON coming from expo-modules-autolinking"

Tags: react-native, expo, podfile, eas

I am trying to upgrade from Expo-48 to Expo-49 by doing the following:

```
expo upgrade
npx expo install --fix
expo prebuild
eas build --profile development --platform ios
```

and then I have the error at installing the pods in the dashboard of EXPO
see below
my dependencies are:

```
"@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util": "^5.0.0",
"@config-plugins/react-native-pdf": "^5.0.0",
"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
"@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.4",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.4.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.7",
"@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.3",
"bad-words": "^3.0.4",
"dotenv": "^16.0.3",
"expo": "^49.0.0",
"expo-av": "~13.4.1",
"expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
"expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
"expo-checkbox": "~2.4.0",
"expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
"expo-dev-client": "~2.4.6",
"expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
"expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
"expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
"expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
"expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
"expo-modules-autolinking": "^1.5.0",
"expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
"expo-screen-capture": "~5.3.0",
"expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
"expo-speech": "~11.3.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
"expo-store-review": "~6.4.0",
"expo-updates": "~0.18.11",
"expo-video-thumbnails": "~7.4.0",
"expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
"fbjs": "^3.0.4",
"firebase": "^9.21.0",
"js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.3",
"react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.2",
"react-native-compressor": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
"react-native-mmkv": "^2.8.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
"react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.6.2",
"react-native-purchases": "^5.13.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
"react-native-redash": "^18.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
"react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
"react-query": "^3.39.2",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
"throttle-debounce": "^5.0.0",
"tus-js-client": "^3.0.1",
"uuid-random": "^1.3.2"
```

The error that then in the eas dashboard comes is the following:

```
[!] Invalid Podfile file: Couldn't parse JSON coming from expo-modules-autolinking command:***
{"extraDependencies":{"androidMavenRepos":[],"iosPods":{}},"modules":[{"packageName":"expo","packageVersion":"49.0.7","pods":[{"podName":"Expo","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo"}],"swiftModuleNames":["Expo"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-application","packageVersion":"5.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"EXApplication","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXApplication"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-av","packageVersion":"13.4.1","pods":[{"podName":"EXAV","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-av/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXAV"],"modules":["VideoViewModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-camera","packageVersion":"13.4.2","pods":[{"podName":"EXCamera","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-camera/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXCamera"],"modules":["CameraViewModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-constants","packageVersion":"14.4.2","pods":[{"podName":"EXConstants","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXConstants"],"modules":["ConstantsModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-dev-client","packageVersion":"2.4.6","pods":[{"podName":"expo-dev-client","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-dev-client/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["expo_dev_client"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-dev-launcher","packageVersion":"2.4.8","pods":[{"podName":"expo-dev-launcher","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-dev-launcher"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXDevLauncher"],"modules":["DevLauncherInternal","DevLauncherAuth","RNCSafeAreaProviderManager"],"appDelegateSubscribers":["ExpoDevLauncherAppDelegateSubscriber"],"reactDelegateHandlers":["ExpoDevLauncherReactDelegateHandler"],"debugOnly":true},{"packageName":"expo-dev-menu","packageVersion":"3.1.8","pods":[{"podName":"expo-dev-menu","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-dev-menu"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXDevMenu"],"modules":["DevMenuModule","DevMenuInternalModule","DevMenuPreferences","RNCSafeAreaProviderManager"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":["ExpoDevMenuReactDelegateHandler"],"debugOnly":true},{"packageName":"expo-dev-menu-interface","packageVersion":"1.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"expo-dev-menu-interface","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-dev-menu-interface/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["expo_dev_menu_interface"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-document-picker","packageVersion":"11.5.4","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoDocumentPicker","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-document-picker/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoDocumentPicker"],"modules":["DocumentPickerModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-eas-client","packageVersion":"0.6.0","pods":[{"podName":"EASClient","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-eas-client/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EASClient"],"modules":["EASClientModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-file-system","packageVersion":"15.4.3","pods":[{"podName":"EXFileSystem","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-file-system/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXFileSystem"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-font","packageVersion":"11.4.0","pods":[{"podName":"EXFont","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-font/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXFont"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-image-loader","packageVersion":"4.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"EXImageLoader","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXImageLoader"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-image-manipulator","packageVersion":"11.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoImageManipulator","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-image-manipulator/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoImageManipulator"],"modules":["ImageManipulatorModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-image-picker","packageVersion":"14.3.2","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoImagePicker","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-image-picker/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoImagePicker"],"modules":["ImagePickerModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-json-utils","packageVersion":"0.7.1","pods":[{"podName":"EXJSONUtils","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-json-utils/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXJSONUtils"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-keep-awake","packageVersion":"12.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoKeepAwake","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoKeepAwake"],"modules":["KeepAwakeModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-linear-gradient","packageVersion":"12.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoLinearGradient","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoLinearGradient"],"modules":["LinearGradientModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-manifests","packageVersion":"0.7.1","pods":[{"podName":"EXManifests","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-manifests/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXManifests"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-media-library","packageVersion":"15.4.1","pods":[{"podName":"EXMediaLibrary","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-media-library/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXMediaLibrary"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-modules-core","packageVersion":"1.5.9","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoModulesCore","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoModulesCore"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-notifications","packageVersion":"0.20.1","pods":[{"podName":"EXNotifications","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-notifications/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXNotifications"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-screen-capture","packageVersion":"5.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"EXScreenCapture","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-screen-capture/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["EXScreenCapture"],"modules":[],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-secure-store","packageVersion":"12.3.1","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoSecureStore","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-secure-store/ios"}],"swiftModuleNames":["ExpoSecureStore"],"modules":["SecureStoreModule"],"appDelegateSubscribers":[],"reactDelegateHandlers":[],"debugOnly":false},{"packageName":"expo-speech","packageVersion":"11.3.0","pods":[{"podName":"ExpoSpeech","podspecDir":"/Users/expo/worki
'.
from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Podfile:43
target 'appname' do
use_expo_modules! !!! error here !!!
config = use_native_modules!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that expo has apparently issues with dynamic app.config.json so I only had to delete that file and everything worked. (Now I only have app.json)

Comment: It is true there might be a problem with the dynamic config, but you don't have to delete it. In my case, I had a `console.debug` call inside of that config and as expo seemingly just takes some script's output, it could not figure out what to do with the outputted log as it expects a JSON to be parsed. TLDR; DO NOT USE CONSOLE.LOGS IN THE CONFIG FILE.

Comment: > TLDR; DO NOT USE CONSOLE.LOGS IN THE CONFIG FILE

this is the reason. expo logs stuff during the build phase, just to read the output from the console and do something with it. if we log stuff we break that

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was with an old node version.
I had 12.2.0, using NVM I changed to 16.17.1 and **pod install** did not complain.
If you are using NVM, you can view the list of node versions with:

```
nvm list
```

And then

```
nvm use 16.17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install @expo/config-plugins`

Comment: please explain the purpose of that command  ... update the answer ... **do not** add a comment